# Heroku NodeJS deploy

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm

I've tried to deploy my NodeJS project to Heroku. I use free account. When I deployed it I visited the page in the browser and it says: ***An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.*** I checked the app's logs and it shows that NodeJS cannot find module: `Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'`. OK, I installed it and again the same error but the logs showed that another module is missing. When I installed and this module the error was again on the page. I checked all modules in `npm list` and noticed all of these modules are installed but under express. The most strange is that the app is running perfectly on localhost. The problem occurs only in Heroku. Also I tried to recover an old version of the app but the page again showed error. How I can fix that problem?

Comment: Is `merge-descriptors` in your `package.json`?

Comment: @roflmyeggo Now no. But when is was it says that another module is missing.

Comment: What happens when you run `npm install express --save` and then redeploy? Or run that command from your Heroku instance.

Comment: Again the same error: `Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'`

Comment: Try the same thing with `npm update` (on either your localhost then redeploy or on the Heroku instance).

Comment: Nothing new... I noticed that npm didn't update anything from express. The same module is missing.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: `{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "***",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.x",
    "npm": "2.11.x"
  },
  "author": "***",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.12.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "io": "^0.1.10",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.8"
  }
}
`

Comment: You are missing the `merge-descriptors` dependency. Run `npm install merge-descriptors --save`. Even though merge-descriptors is a dependency of the express npm package, Heroku doesn't seem to want to install it when it runs `npm install` on your `package.json`.

Comment: I've done it this before. Now it says another module is missing: `Error: Cannot find module 'finalhandler'`. Now if I install and this module it will want to install the next module. But WHY? When on localhost it is running and before also was running on heroku without these installed modules?

Comment: Make sure your localhost installation is not relying on any global package installations. `cd` into your project directory and run `rm -rf node_modules; npm install --production` then see if your application still runs.

Comment: @roflmyeggo I did the instructions but again without success.

Comment: The previous instructions were for your localhost to make sure that you have the correct `package.json` dependencies and that you are not relying on global packages.

Comment: @roflmyeggo Yes, and it installed some new dependencies but heroku log didn't change

Comment: Can I set the mode of node in the Procfile from? Because it is not set to ENV but it is known that node on heroku is in production mode.

Comment: Try it on your local production where it is currently working to verify the correctness of your `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 npm install merge-descriptors safer-buffer --save
```

Then, repush to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the repo actually has the Node Modules folder, my issue was with .gitignore...